# How to get multiple ajax responses in one function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function, response

I don't know if it's possible, but i'm trying to get multiple ajax responses and access it's values in another function.

I actually get the responses (twice each), but i'm not able to return the responses individual values.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/GabrielS0uza/kc4exbyw/)

```js
function firstResponse() {
  const response1 = $.ajax({
    url: 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random',
    method: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json',
  });

  response1.done(function(response1) {
    test(response1);
  })
}

function secondResponse() {
  const response2 = $.ajax({
    url: 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://official-joke-api.appspot.com/random_joke',
    method: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json',
  });

  response2.done(function(response2) {
    test(response2);
  })
}

firstResponse();
secondResponse();

function test(response1, response2) {
  console.log('Response 1', response1);
  console.log('Response 2', response2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Response 2 is alway `undefined`, since both call to `test` never pass second param `response2`

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to achieve that. I personally would go with `promises`.

```
function firstResponse() {
  return $.ajax({
    url: 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random',
    method: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json'
  });
}

function secondResponse() {
  return $.ajax({
    url: 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://official-joke-api.appspot.com/random_joke',
    method: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json'
  });
}

function test() {
  Promise.all([
    firstResponse(), 
    secondResponse()
  ]).then(result => {
    console.log(result);
  });
}

test();
```

In the `test` function you call a `Promise.all` which waits for all the individual promises to be resolved and outputs the result as an array in the order the of the promises passed to it at the time of calling.

Comment: `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $.ajax({ ....}) ...})` - or, as I would do it - `return $.ajax({....})` - because jQuery.ajax returns a promise (of sorts) - or even `return Promise.resolve($ajax({...}))` to remove some quirks of early jquery promises

Answer (score 0):

```
let urls = ['https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random',
    'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://official-joke-api.appspot.com/random_joke'];

let structure = {
    method: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json',
};

async function first() {
    try {
        const response = await $.ajax({
            url: urls[0],
            structure,
        });

        return response;
    } catch(error) {
        // Error
    }

}

async function second() {
    try {
        const response = await $.ajax({
            url: urls[1],
            structure,
        });

        return response;
    } catch(error) {
        // Error
    }
}

async function test() {
    let response = await ('s')
    return response
}

first()
    .then(() => second());
```

Answer (score -4):

Ajax calls are asynchronous so if you want to handle the two results in one function you have to do a counter yourself, something like this for the simplest kind:

```
function firstResponse() {
  const response1 = $.ajax({
    url: 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random',
    method: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json',
  });

  response1.done(function(response1) {
    test("response1", response1);
  })
}

function secondResponse() {
  const response2 = $.ajax({
    url: 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://official-joke-api.appspot.com/random_joke',
    method: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json',
  });

  response2.done(function(response2) {
    test("response2", response2);
  })
}

var responses = [];

firstResponse();
secondResponse();

function test(index, data) {
  responses[index] = data;
  if (Object.keys(responses).length === 2) processResponses();
}

function processResponses() {
  console.log(responses);
}
```

There are various more advanced way to handle it, like using async/await or something, but this should get your work done without much modification to your existing code.

UPDATE: for the async/await way which is my preferred way of doing things nowadays:

```
(async () => {
  const response1 = await $.ajax({
    url: 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random',
    method: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json',
  });

  const response2 = await $.ajax({
    url: 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://official-joke-api.appspot.com/random_joke',
    method: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json',
  });

  console.log(response1);
  console.log(response2);

})();
```

Comment: if you don't want it to run synchronously, you can always use the more crude method above instead, I don't see anything in the question asked against running the two requests synchronously, just that handling two requests in one function, where handling them synchronously is fine IMHO.